# Where exactly is permutation happening in equation 5 of the paper "Learning with Sets in Multiple Instance Regression Applied to Remote Sensing"?

Tags: papers, long-short-term-memory, attention, notation

I am reading the article [Learning with Sets in Multiple Instance Regression Applied to Remote Sensing](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1903.07745/) about creating an embedding which is order-invariant to inputs ($m_{l}$). They referred to order-invariance in eq (5) as follows:

> The order-invariant operation happens in (5), where permuting $m_l$
> with $m_{l}'$ yields the same vector $r_t$, due to the summation.

First, what exactly is $m_{l}'$? Is it the transpose of $m_l$?

Second, how is permutation happening?

$$r_t=\sum\nolimits_{l=1}^{L_i}a_{l,t}m_l$$

Here, equation (5) in the paper, $m_l$ points to the $l^{th}$ vector, $a_{l,t}$ is merely some scalar weight, and $r_t$ is the vector returned.